# Can a jinn take a person as a wife/husband?

Tags: jinn

Assalaamu 'alaikum.

I have a question, i have heard true readings, that i have a Spiritual boyfriend/husband, that is very jealous n it has ruin any relationship that i get into. Is this possible?

From my own experience i haven't had a boyfriend longer than a year, and every time i've found someone, and talked about marriage, the person at the end of the relationship abandons me without any reason that is good enough.

I experience that sometimes when i am bout to sleep, it feels like somebody is pressing me down so it gets very hard to get up, n i have in my dreams seen a manlike figure coming towards me with flame on his whole body saying "it is me" and then have a sexual intercourse with me in my dreams..

I am very stressed cos it feels like my life is being taken away from me, since am getting older, and very much mature for marriage. I don't know who to ask for advice..

I pray daily 5 times a day, and i recite Surat al Naas, Surat al Falaaq and Ayatul Kursi, when am ready for bed, but these things still happens sometimes (what am i doing wrong since these Surahs are meant to protect me?)

I have had my period for over 2weeks (1st time) this means that i can not pray, which is the only thing that gives me comfort..

Please Is there anything i can do, or Surahs i can recite to get this away?

Am very stressed about my situation..

From afraid sister

Comment: This thing sounds familiar to me. This question requires some heavy cleaning. Welcome to [islam.se] anyways.

Comment: If it helps, the protection you get by reciting verses from the Quran or praying is coming from God. It's not the reciting that is protecting you, it's God that is protecting you. You can recite all night long, but if he doesn't like to, he won't protect you.

So, it's good to know that it's not the Surahs that are meant to protect you. If you trust God, he will protect you. I am not saying though that you should stop reciting.

Also, being afraid makes it worse (in a psychological point of view).

May God protect you against all harm!

Answer (score 4):

Praise be to Allah.

First of all, I'd like to congratulate you, sister, for being serious about Allah's Deen, praying 5 times a day and following the Sunnah of the Prophet (SAWS) to ward off evil by reciting Ayatul Kursi, Suraah Falaq wa Naas before going to sleep. It is very good that you're concerned about such a serious issue and didn't hesitate to ask a question regarding this. May Allah give you excellent reward for this and alleviate your sufferings and troubles as soon as possible. Ameen.

But, I'd also like to remind you, as a fellow Muslim, that it's not permissible for a female to get involved in an extra-marital/pre-marital relationship with a non-mahram male. May Allah make it easier for you to stay away from such relationships and get married as soon as possible. Ameen.

With regards to the situation you described, you must first be absolutely sure whether the things that are happening to you are really supernatural stuff i.e. a Jinn is *indeed* involved in it, or is it a human being, posing as a Jinn, and, Astaghfirullah he is violating you, Allah forbid. But if you're sure that it's a Jinn, it is very likely that this Jinn is an evil Jinn, and you should try your best to ward him off. You should not even consider getting married to him. Contact a qualified Shaykh who performs 'Ruqya' and highly skilled at exorcism according to Qur'an and Sunnah. Tell him everything and ask him for help. And above all, make a lot of du'a to Allah Subhanahu wa Ta'ala for getting you out of these bad events.

With regards to your question whether a Jinn can take a person as wife/husband, it can be answered from two perspectives:

1. Whether it is **possible** for a human being to get married to a Jinn
2. Whether it is **permissible** for a human being to get married to a Jinn

**Perspective - 1**: It is extremely rare, but not impossible.
**Perspective - 2**: Majority of the classical scholars from all school of thought, especially scholars from the Hanafi, Shafi'i and Hambali school of thought have stated that such a marriage is not permissible. Only Imam Malik didn't directly oppose such a marriage, but he stated his dislike for these type of marriage and hence, according to the Maliki School of Thought, it is considered as Makrooh. Among the scholars from the Hanafi school of thought the most notable are Qadhi Badr al-Din al-Shibli al-Hanafi and 'Allama Ibn Abidin Al Shaami who said it's not permissible. Among the scholars from the Shafi'i school of thought was Imam Jalaluddin Suyooti and Imam Khatib al-Shirbini. For more information, please refer to this [link](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5412)

**Summary** : Sister, you should try your best to stay away from being involved in any sorts of extra-marital relationship and instead, try to get married soon. Contact good sisters so that they may help you find a nice and religiously committed Muslim guy to get married to. Ask Allah's help to get married soon, He won't disappoint you. You must ensure that the encounters you faced is not a human affair and it was indeed a supernatural event. If that is so, you should make no delay and contact a qualified Shaykh who do Ruqya and Exorcism and is skillful. It is possible to get married to Jinns but classical scholars of almost all Schools of Thoughts have given Fatwa that it's not permissible,except Imam Malik. Even if it were permissible, it can only be done to Muslim and good Jinns, and not to evil and Kaafir Jinns. Based on your description, it seems the Jinn who's bothering you is an evil Jinn and most likely to be Kaafir. So you can't marry him.

And Allah knows Best, and He is the source of all Strength.

Answer (score 1):

Aslaamu'alaykom wa rahmatula wa barakatu, I can relate to the feeling of someone/thing pushing me down when im falling asleep worried, I went to my Ustaad and asked what I should I do and he told me to always make whudu before going to bed and say Allahuakbar 11 times,  Subahanallh 11 times then Ahumdulilah 11 times and to recite a dua for sleeping like "Allah huma bismika 'amutu wa'ahyah". This has made a big difference for me, it really helps I sleep peacefully now! Try it and it will work for you sister as it has worked for me insha Allah!

Answer (score -2):

Salam!

Ok what you're going through I have and am. When I first found out about my Jinn I thought I was going crazy. Literally loosing my mind. I spent hours on the internet on islamic and non islamic websites trying to find answers. Nothing really helped me. What helped me was coming to terms with what was happening and take control. I did what normally people wouldnt do or recommend. I befriended my Jinn. Luckily he's a good muslim Jinn whose cooperative so once I stood my ground and drew a line letting him know he cannot cross it in any circumstances, everything got better. On the bright side he actually helps me when it comes to finding a husband. When a potential is presented he would tell me if they are who they claim to be or liars. I always give them the benefit of doubt but sooner or later turns out my jinn is always right. In your case I recommend trying to get rid of it. He doesnt seem like a a muslim Jinn rather then a evil one. Trust me its not hard to get rid of Jinns. They fear you more then you fear them. Me and my Jinn have helped others get rid of any bad jinns and your isnt good.